# Transaction halted with a RUNTIME ERROR

Tags: truffle, contract-debugging, solidity-0.5.x

while debugging I encountered this error: There was no revert message.  This may be due to an in intentional halting expression, such as assert(), revert(), or require(), or could be due to an unintentional exception such as out-of-gas exceptions.
Please inspect your transaction parameters and contract code to determine the meaning of this error. Upon inspection in the debugger here is what I see:

```
debug(development:0x5bc93fa0...)> :game.player1
'0x1F527104D6F570B7523f6BaF0278e0eB5BD76871'

debug(development:0x5bc93fa0...)> :player
0x1F527104D6F570B7523f6BaF0278e0eB5BD76871
```

It appears that game.player1 is the same as player but I don't know exactly why.
Debug console:

````
TakeShareContract.sol:

221:         address player = msg.sender;
222:         require(game.registerationOpen);
223:         require(game.player1 != player); // Can also put ```require(game.registered[player]);``` meaning, Same player cannot join the game.
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

debug(development:0x5bc93fa0...)> n

Transaction halted with a RUNTIME ERROR.

There was no revert message.  This may be due to an in intentional halting expression, such as assert(), revert(), or require(), or could be due to an unintentional exception such as out-of-gas exceptions.
Please inspect your transaction parameters and contract code to determine the meaning of this error.
````

Smart Contract Code:

````
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract owned { 
    address owner;
    modifier onlyOwner()
    {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
}

contract priced {
    modifier costs(uint256 price) {
        require(msg.value <= price);
        _;
    }
}

contract TakeShareContract is owned, priced {

    //Global Variables
    uint constant TAKE = 0;
    uint constant SHARE = 1;
    mapping(address=>bool) suspended;
    mapping(address=>uint) totalGamesStarted;
    mapping(address=>uint) totalGamesParticipated;   
    uint256 contractEarnings = 0;
    //Game Rules
    uint256 REGISTRATION_COST = 10**14;// 0.0001 Ether //Editable by Owner
    uint256 MINIMUM_COST_OF_BET = 10**17;// 0.1 Ether //Editable by Owner
    uint256 MAXIMUM_COST_OF_BET = 5 * 10**18;//5 Ether //Editable by Owner
    uint256 STAGE_TIMEOUT = 60*60*24*7;//1 Week

    //Reward Matrix Parameters
    uint256 K = 25; //Editable by Owner

    //Events
    event RegisterationOpened(uint indexed _gameNumber);
    event RegisterationClosed(uint indexed _gameNumber);
    event RevealStart(uint indexed _gameNumber);
    event RevealStop(uint indexed _gameNumber);
    event Transferred(uint indexed _gameNumber,address _to, uint256 _amount);
    event ContractEarnings(uint indexed _gameNumber, uint256 _amount, string _reason);
    event Disqualified(uint indexed _gameNumber, address indexed _player, bytes32 _encryptedChoice, uint _actualChoice, bytes32 _encryptedActualChoice);
    event NewGameRules(uint _oldFees, uint _newFees, uint _oldMinBet, uint _newMinBet, uint _oldMaxBet, uint _newMaxBet, uint _oldStageTimeout, uint _newStageTimeout);
    event NewRewardMatrix(uint _n1, uint _n2, uint _n3, uint _d);
    event NewRewardPercentage(uint256 _oldK, uint256 _k);
    event Suspended(address indexed _player);
    event UnSuspended(address indexed _player);

    //BET Struct
    struct Bet {
        bytes32 encryptedChoice;
        uint256 betAmount;
        uint actualChoice;
    }

    //GAME Struct
    struct Game {
        uint startTime;
        uint revealTime;
        uint finishTime;
        address player1; 
        address player2;
        uint256 registrationCost;
        uint256 k;
        uint stageTimeout;
        bool registerationOpen;
        bool revealing;
        bool lastGameFinished;
        mapping(address=>address) opponent;
        mapping(address=>bool) registered;
        mapping(address=>Bet) bets;
        mapping(address=>bool) revealed;
        mapping(address=>bool) disqualified;
        mapping(address=>bool) claimedReward;
        mapping(address=>uint256) reward;
    }

    Game[] games;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }   

    function fund() payable external {
        contractEarnings = contractEarnings + msg.value;
    }

    // UTILITY METHODS STARTS
    function isEven(uint num) private pure returns(bool _isEven) {
        uint halfNum = num / 2;
        return (halfNum * 2) == num;
    }
    // UTILITY METHODS END

    // ADMIN METHODS START
    function changeOwner(address _to) public onlyOwner {
        require(_to != address(0));
        owner = _to;
    }
    /** @dev So Owner can't TAKE away player's money in the middle of the game.
    Owner can only withdraw earnings of the game contract and not the entire balance.
    Earnings are calculated after every game is finished, i.e.; when both players
    have cliamed reward. If a player doens't claim reward for a game, those ether 
    can not be reclaimed until 1 week. After 1 week Owner of contract has power of disqualifying 
    Players who did not finihs the game. FAIR ENOUGH ?
    */
    //function transferEarningsToOwner() public onlyOwner {
        //require(address(this).balance >= contractEarnings);
        //uint256 _contractEarnings = contractEarnings;
        //contractEarnings = 0;
        // VERY IMPORTANT
        // PREVENTS REENTRANCY ATTACK BY CONTRACT OWNER
        // contract Earnings need to be set to 0 first,
        // and then transferred to owner
     //   owner.transfer(_contractEarnings);
    //}

    function suspend(address _player) public onlyOwner returns(bool _suspended){
        require(!suspended[_player]);
        require(_player != owner);
        suspended[_player] = true;
        emit Suspended(_player);
        return true;
    }

    function unSuspend(address _player) public onlyOwner returns(bool _unSuspended){
        require(suspended[_player]);
        suspended[_player] = false;
        emit UnSuspended(_player);
        return true;
    }

    function setRewardPercentageK(uint256 _k) public onlyOwner {
        //Max earnings is double.
        require(_k <= 100);
        emit NewRewardPercentage(K, _k);
        K = _k;
    }

    function setGameRules(uint256 _fees, uint256 _minBet, uint256 _maxBet, uint256 _stageTimeout) public onlyOwner {
        require(_stageTimeout >= 60*60*24*7);//Owner can't set it to below 1 week
        require((_fees * 100 ) < _minBet);//Fees will always be less that 1 % of bet
        require(_minBet < _maxBet);
        emit NewGameRules(REGISTRATION_COST, _fees, MINIMUM_COST_OF_BET, _minBet, MAXIMUM_COST_OF_BET, _maxBet, STAGE_TIMEOUT, _stageTimeout);
        REGISTRATION_COST = _fees;
        MINIMUM_COST_OF_BET = _minBet;
        MAXIMUM_COST_OF_BET = _maxBet;
        STAGE_TIMEOUT = _stageTimeout;
    }
    //ADMIN METHODS ENDS

    //VIEW APIs STARTS
    function getOwner() public view returns(address _owner) {
        return owner;
    }

    function getContractBalance() public view returns(uint256 _balance) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function getContractEarnings() public view returns(uint _earnings) {
        return contractEarnings;
    }

    function getRewardMatrix() public view returns(uint _k) {
        return (K);
    }

    function getGameRules() public view returns(uint256 _fees, uint256 _minBet, uint256 _maxBet, uint256 _stageTimeout) {
        return (REGISTRATION_COST, MINIMUM_COST_OF_BET, MAXIMUM_COST_OF_BET, STAGE_TIMEOUT);
    }

    function getGameState(uint gameNumber) public view returns(bool _registerationOpen, bool _revealing, bool _lastGameFinished, uint _startTime, uint _revealTime, uint _finishTime, uint _stageTimeout) {
        require(games.length >= gameNumber);    
        Game storage game = games[gameNumber - 1];    
        return (game.registerationOpen, game.revealing, game.lastGameFinished, game.startTime, game.revealTime, game.finishTime, game.stageTimeout);
    }

    function getPlayerState(uint gameNumber) public view returns(bool _suspended, bool _registered, bool _revealed, bool _disqualified, bool _claimedReward, uint256 _betAmount, uint256 _reward) {
        require(games.length >= gameNumber);
        uint index = gameNumber - 1;
        address player = msg.sender;
        uint256 betAmount = games[index].bets[player].betAmount;
        return (suspended[player], games[index].registered[player], games[index].revealed[player], games[index].disqualified[player], games[index].claimedReward[player], betAmount, games[index].reward[player] );
    }

    function getTotalGamesStarted() public view returns(uint _totalGames) {
        return totalGamesStarted[msg.sender];
    }

    function getTotalGamesParticipated() public view returns(uint _totalGames) {
        return totalGamesParticipated[msg.sender];
    }

    function getTotalGames() public view returns(uint _totalGames) {
        return games.length;
    }
    //VIEW APIs ENDS

    //GAME PLAY STARTS
    function startGame(uint256 _betAmount, bytes32 _encryptedChoice) public payable costs(_betAmount) returns(uint _gameNumber) {
        address player = msg.sender;
        require(!suspended[player]);   
        //require(_betAmount >= MINIMUM_COST_OF_BET);
        require(_betAmount <= MAXIMUM_COST_OF_BET);
        Game memory _game = Game(now, now, now, player, address(0), REGISTRATION_COST, K, STAGE_TIMEOUT, true, false, false);  
        games.push(_game); 
        Game storage game = games[games.length-1]; 
        game.registered[player] = true;
        game.bets[player] = Bet(_encryptedChoice, _betAmount, 0);                   
        totalGamesStarted[player] = totalGamesStarted[player] + 1;
        emit RegisterationOpened(games.length);
        return games.length;
    }

    function joinGame(uint _gameNumber, uint256 _betAmount, bytes32 _encryptedChoice) public  payable costs(_betAmount) {
        require(games.length >= _gameNumber);
        Game storage game = games[_gameNumber-1];
        address player = msg.sender;
        require(game.registerationOpen); 
        require(game.player1 != player); // Can also put ```require(game.registered[player]);``` meaning, Same player cannot join the game.
        require(!suspended[player]);   
        require(_betAmount >= MINIMUM_COST_OF_BET);
        require(_betAmount <= MAXIMUM_COST_OF_BET);
        require(game.player2 == address(0)); 
        game.player2 = player;
        game.registered[player] = true;
        game.bets[player] = Bet(_encryptedChoice, _betAmount, 0);    
        game.registerationOpen = false;
        game.revealing = true;  
        game.revealTime = now; // Set Game Reveal time in order to resolve dead lock if no one claims reward.
        game.finishTime = now; // If both do not reveal for one week, Admin can immidiately finish game.
        game.opponent[game.player1] = game.player2;    
        game.opponent[game.player2] = game.player1;
        totalGamesParticipated[player] = totalGamesParticipated[player] + 1;
        emit RegisterationClosed(_gameNumber);
        emit RevealStart(_gameNumber);
    }

    function reveal(uint _gameNumber, uint256 _choice) public {
        require(games.length >= _gameNumber);
        Game storage game = games[_gameNumber-1];
        require(game.revealing);
        address player = msg.sender;
        require(!suspended[player]);
        require(game.registered[player]);
        require(!game.revealed[player]);
        game.revealed[player] = true;
        game.bets[player].actualChoice = _choice;
        bytes32 encryptedChoice = game.bets[player].encryptedChoice;
        bytes32 encryptedActualChoice = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_choice));
        if( encryptedActualChoice != encryptedChoice) {
            game.disqualified[player] = true;
            //Mark them as Claimed Reward so that 
            //contract earnings can be accounted for
            game.claimedReward[player] = true;
            game.reward[player] = 0;
            if (game.disqualified[game.opponent[player]]) {
                uint256 gameEarnings = game.bets[player].betAmount + game.bets[game.opponent[player]].betAmount;
                contractEarnings = contractEarnings + gameEarnings;
                emit ContractEarnings(_gameNumber, gameEarnings, "BOTH_DISQUALIFIED");
            }
            emit Disqualified(_gameNumber, player, encryptedChoice, _choice, encryptedActualChoice);
        }
        if(game.revealed[game.player1] && game.revealed[game.player2]) {
            game.revealing = false;
            game.lastGameFinished = true;
            game.finishTime = now; //Set Game finish time in order to resolve dead lock if no one claims reward.
            emit RevealStop(_gameNumber);
        }
    }
    //GAME PLAY ENDS


    //REWARD WITHDRAW STARTS
    function ethTransfer(uint gameNumber, address _to, uint256 _amount) private {
        require(!suspended[_to]);
        require(_to != address(0));
        if ( _amount > games[gameNumber-1].registrationCost) {
            //TAKE game Commission
            uint256 amount = _amount - games[gameNumber-1].registrationCost;
            require(address(this).balance >= amount);
            _to.call(abi.encode(amount));
            emit Transferred(gameNumber, _to, amount);
        }
    }


    function claimRewardK(uint gameNumber) public returns(bool _claimedReward)  {
        require(games.length >= gameNumber);
        Game storage game = games[gameNumber-1];
        address player = msg.sender;
        require(!suspended[player]);
        require(!game.claimedReward[player]);
        uint commission = games[gameNumber-1].registrationCost;
        if (game.registerationOpen) {
            game.claimedReward[player] = true;
            game.registerationOpen = false;
            game.lastGameFinished = true;
            if ( now > (game.startTime + game.stageTimeout)) {
                //No commision if game was open till stage timeout.
                commission = 0;
            }
            game.reward[player] = game.bets[player].betAmount - commission;
            if (commission > 0) {
                contractEarnings = contractEarnings + commission;
                emit ContractEarnings(gameNumber, commission, "GAME_ABANDONED");
            }
            //Bet amount can't be less than commission.
            //Hence no -ve check is required
            ethTransfer(gameNumber, player, game.bets[player].betAmount);
            return true;
        }
        require(game.lastGameFinished);
        require(!game.disqualified[player]);
        require(game.registered[player]);
        require(game.revealed[player]);
        require(!game.claimedReward[player]);
        game.claimedReward[player] = true;
        address opponent = game.opponent[player];
        uint256 reward = 0;
        uint256 gameReward = 0;
        uint256 totalBet = (game.bets[player].betAmount + game.bets[opponent].betAmount);
        if ( game.disqualified[opponent]) {
            gameReward = ((100 + game.k) * game.bets[player].betAmount) / 100;
            reward = gameReward < totalBet ? gameReward : totalBet; //Min (X+Y, (100+K)*X/100)
            game.reward[player] = reward - commission;
            //Min (X+Y, (100+K)*X/100) can't be less than commision.
            //Hence no -ve check is required
            contractEarnings = contractEarnings + (totalBet - game.reward[player]);
            emit ContractEarnings(gameNumber, (totalBet - game.reward[player]), "OPPONENT_DISQUALIFIED");
            ethTransfer(gameNumber, player, reward);
            return true;
        }
        if ( !isEven(game.bets[player].actualChoice) && !isEven(game.bets[opponent].actualChoice) ) { // SHARE SHARE
            reward = (game.bets[player].betAmount + game.bets[opponent].betAmount) / 2;
            game.reward[player] = reward - commission;
            //(X+Y)/2 can't be less than commision.
            //Hence no -ve check is required
            if ( game.claimedReward[opponent] ) {
                uint256 gameEarnings = (totalBet - game.reward[player] - game.reward[opponent]);
                contractEarnings = contractEarnings + gameEarnings;
                emit ContractEarnings(gameNumber, gameEarnings, "SHARE_SHARE");
            }
            ethTransfer(gameNumber, player, reward);
            return true;
        }
        if ( !isEven(game.bets[player].actualChoice) && isEven(game.bets[opponent].actualChoice) ) { // SHARE TAKE
            game.reward[player] = 0;
            if ( game.claimedReward[opponent] ) {
                uint256 gameEarnings = (totalBet - game.reward[player] - game.reward[opponent]);
                contractEarnings = contractEarnings + gameEarnings;
                emit ContractEarnings(gameNumber, gameEarnings, "SHARE_TAKE");
            }
            return true;
        }
        if ( isEven(game.bets[player].actualChoice) && !isEven(game.bets[opponent].actualChoice) ) { // TAKE SHARE
            gameReward = (((100 + game.k) * game.bets[player].betAmount)/100);
            reward = gameReward < totalBet ? gameReward : totalBet; 
            game.reward[player] = reward - commission;
            //Min (X+Y, (100+K)*X/100) can't be less than commision.
            //Hence no -ve check is required
            if ( game.claimedReward[opponent] ) {
                uint256 gameEarnings = (totalBet - game.reward[player] - game.reward[opponent]);
                contractEarnings = contractEarnings + gameEarnings;
                emit ContractEarnings(gameNumber, gameEarnings, "TAKE_SHARE");
            }
            ethTransfer(gameNumber, player, reward);
            return true;
        }
        if ( isEven(game.bets[player].actualChoice) && isEven(game.bets[opponent].actualChoice) ) { // TAKE TAKE
            reward = 0;
            if( game.bets[player].betAmount > game.bets[opponent].betAmount) {
                //((100-K)*(X-Y)/2)/100 will always be less than X+Y so no need for min check on X+Y and reward
                reward = ((100 - game.k) * (game.bets[player].betAmount - game.bets[opponent].betAmount) / 2) / 100;
            }
            if(reward > 0) {
                //((100-K)*(X-Y)/2)/100 CAN BE LESS THAN COMMISSION.
                game.reward[player] = reward > commission ? reward - commission : 0;
            }
            if ( game.claimedReward[opponent] ) {
                uint256 gameEarnings = (totalBet - game.reward[player] - game.reward[opponent]);
                contractEarnings = contractEarnings + gameEarnings;
                emit ContractEarnings(gameNumber, gameEarnings, "TAKE_TAKE");
            }
            ethTransfer(gameNumber, player, reward);
            return true;
        }
    }
    //REWARD WITHDRAW ENDS
}
````

Comment: Which function are you calling? What parameters are you using? The failing condition `require(game.player1 != player)` implies you are using the same player twice and the contract doesn't accept that.

Comment: I'm calling the joinGame with the gamenumber, betAmount, and odd or even choice: ```instance.joinGame("1", "2", "0x2a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")```

Comment: Did you call startGame and joinGame from the same account? The contract enforces that two different accounts are required play.